# Оттягиваемый ScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Нужно сделать так называемый оттягиваемый scroolview. То есть в нем есть элемент вверху,  который видно не полностью, его можно увидить если начать оттягивать ScroolView. Я думал может отрицательным margin можно такого эффекта добиться, но как то не вышло

Comment: Попробуйте программно проскролить немного ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Реализация на Kotlin. Там все просто и по аналогии можно на `Java` сделать

```
class BounceScrollView : ScrollView {
    private val MAX_Y_OVER_SCROLL_DISTANCE = 40
    private var mMaxYOverScrollDistance: Int 
        = (context.resources.displayMetrics.density * MAX_Y_OVER_SCROLL_DISTANCE).toInt()

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    override fun overScrollBy(deltaX: Int,
                              deltaY: Int,
                              scrollX: Int,
                              scrollY: Int,
                              scrollRangeX: Int,
                              scrollRangeY: Int,
                              maxOverScrollX: Int,
                              maxOverScrollY: Int,
                              isTouchEvent: Boolean): Boolean {

        //функция вызывается при "оттягивании" view

        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, mMaxYOverScrollDistance, isTouchEvent)
    }
}
```